# Does Luracast Restler support multi-part URIs?

Tags: rest, mapping, uri

I've recently started a project using Luracast Restler. It seems a very simple and effective way to set up a REST API. With very little code, I was able to provide CRUD services for my Category and Product resources.
My GET methods look like this:

```
class Categories
{
    function get($id=NULL) {
        if (isset($id))
            {
                // return category details for $id.
            }
            else
            {
                // return all categories.
            }
    }
}

class Products
{
    function get($id=NULL) {
        if (isset($id))
        {
            // return product details for $id.
        }
        else
        {
            // return all products.
        }
    }
}
```

Clients can get the details of the "books" category using:
    http:api/categories/books

or all categories using:
    http:api/categories

Same for products. One product:
    http:api/products/123
All products:
    http:api/products

So far so good.
Now I want to progress to something slightly more involved. I want to give my clients access to the products in a category.
I want my URI to be:
    http:api/categories//products

```
E.g.
http:api/categories/books/products
```

and from there, I want to offer:
    http:api/categories//products/

```
E.g.
http:api/categories/books/products/123
```

This gives my client the ability to transfer from one resource to another using a progressive series of links, which I see as a core principle of REST.
But I can't see a way of achieving this with Restler. I've seen some mention of JavaDoc comments being used to specify URI mapping, so I tried this:

```
class Products
{
    /**
    * url GET /categories/:catId/products/:prodId
    */
    function get($catId=NULL, $prodId=NULL) {
        // Get product($prodId) of category($catId)
    }
}
```

But this doesn’t work. Restler doesn’t seem to take any information from the comment; it implicitly creates the URI route based on class name and function name.

Can anyone help? Am I missing something? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine in the example above and what you are trying to achieve except one *simple mistake* that stopped it from working!

Your PHPDoc comment is missing `@`

Change your code as follows

```
<?php
class Products
{
    /**
    * @url GET /categories/:catId/products/:prodId
    */
    function get($catId=NULL, $prodId=NULL) {
        // Get product($prodId) of category($catId)
    }
}
```

Also take a look at the related question 
[How do you organize Luracast Restler classes to create related route endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108276/how-do-you-organize-luracast-restler-classes-to-create-related-route-endpoints)