# How do you organize Luracast Restler classes to create related route endpoints?

Tags: php, api, frameworks

I am working with Luracast Restler API framework and am wondering how to organize the class structures to create this style of route.

```
webroot/user/:id/
webroot/user/:id/profile 
webroot/user/:id/tweets
```

With the possibility of using GET, PUT, POST, DELETE for each:

```
Class user(){
 function get($id){
   Do something when GET/webroot/user/:id/ 
 }
 function put($data){
   Do something when PUT/webroot/user/:data/ 
 }
}
Class profile(){
 function get($id){
   Do something when GET/webroot/user/:id/profile 
 }
}
Class tweets(){
 function get($id){
  Do something when GET/webroot/user/:id/tweets
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Into which concrete problem did you run? What is the official specification and does your class works with it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use custom url routing using the PHP Doc comments. Here is the modified example for your use case.

```
Class User(){
 function get($id){
   //Do something when GET /webroot/user/:id/ 
 }
 function put($data){
   //Do something when PUT /webroot/user/:data/ 
 }
 /**
 * @url GET /:id/profile
 */
 function profile($id){
   //get the profile for specified user
 }
}
```

You can replace the method with POST, DELETE, PUT for profile editing. Also note that you can add more than one route using the syntax above.

Answer (score 1):

Are custom routes allowed on the other CRUD methods?

```
/**
* @url POST /create
*/      
protected function post($request_data=NULL) {
    return $this->dp->insert($this->_validate($request_data));
}
```

I call POST properly

```
Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://myserver.com/base/_006_crud/user>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: ssoid=123&ssotype=facebook&crudID=0&ssoname=mickey.
```

but when I call from my code I get a 404 "Not Found" error"

```
response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```